# $Ext^i(D(R),R)$ for a certain commutative algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $k$ be a field which is not algebraic over a finite field and $a \in k$ an element of infinite multiplicative order.

Let $R=k[V,X,Y,Z]/I$ with $I=<V^2,Z^2,XY,VX+aXZ,VY+YZ,VX+Y^2,VY-X^2>.$

One can show that $R$ is a finite dimensional $k$-algebra of dimension 8.
This algebra appeared in http://s.web.umkc.edu/segal/papers/refl.pdf and seems to be the first example of a finite dimensional algebra having Gorenstein projective modules that are not stable (found about 40 years after the definition of Gorenstein projective modules by Auslander and Bridger).
Let $D=Hom_K(-,K)$ be the natural duality.

Question: Do we have $Ext_R^i(D(R),R) \neq 0$ for infinitely many $i \geq 1$?

Some calculations for small $i$ suggest that this is true even for all $i \geq 1$. Is there a nice reason, possibly without much computations?

In general I am not aware of a general finite dimensional commutative algebra $A$ that is not Gorenstein with $Ext_A^i(D(A),A) =0$ for some $i \geq 1$.